# Primary key property 'name' does not exist on object 'RealmSwiftPermissionRole'

Tags: xcode, realm

I'm using RealmSwift as a database in my swift project. Today, after opening my project in Xcode-beta version 11, my app crash with this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Primary key property 'name' does not exist on object 'RealmSwiftPermissionRole''

My app works properly on the previous version of Xcode(10.2.1).
**RealmSwiftPermissionRole** is a class from the **Realm** and I don't have access to it. Maybe in their feature updates, they fix this bug but for now, I search a lot but didn't find any solution. 
(I clean the project, delete the app from the simulator, and run the project again but nothing changed.)
Any suggestion?

Comment: If it worked in 10.2.1 and not in 11 **BETA** Then the issue is likely the fact that you're building a project on **BETA** software. I would suggest going back to 10.2.1 until 11 is official.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

There's an issue with iOS 13 and Xcode 11 which may cause this problem. All String properties of Realm classes with a default `String` value set are disregarded somehow.
You can fix this by updating to the latest version (currently 3.20.0) and then on Xcode: **Product -> Clean Build Folder**.

If you're using cocoa-pods:

Open your project's Podfile, and replace RealmSwift line with:

```
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 4.4.1'
```

Then, open terminal on the project's folder and:

```
pod repo update
pod install
```

Comment: thanks, updating RealmSwift to 3.20.0 solved problem

Comment: Don't forget to **Clean Build Folder**!

Answer (score 16):

Developers of Realm have started working on [Xcode 11 compatibility](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6163). From that page...

> Using Realm with Xcode betas requires building from source, and typically will require using dev branches rather than releases.
>
> **Carthage**
>
> `github "realm/realm-cocoa" "tg/xcode-11-b1"`
>
> `DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer carthage bootstrap -no-use-binaries`
>
> **CocoaPods**
>
> `pod 'Realm', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'tg/xcode-11-b1', submodules: true`
>
> `pod 'RealmSwift', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'tg/xcode-11-b1', submodules: true`
>
> *Explicitly including the Realm pod as a dependency is required as otherwise it'll try to use the latest release of the obj-c part.*

Note that last sentence. You must include the Realm pod as a dependency or it'll use the non-beta version and it won't work.

Comment: branch is changed to 'master'

Answer (score 11):

I had run into the same issue with RealmSwift 4.3.1, the problem was I forgot to mark the property as *@objc*

```
@objc dynamic var id = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting and reinstalling your application too.

Comment: I did, but not helped

Comment: Can you try updating your pod too if it is error in the realm class.

Answer (score 0):

For me,

Updating the Realm to `pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 4.4.1'`

and update the `pod install`

Works for me.