# can't install pod correctly

Tags: ios, swift

I trying to use `FolioReaderKit` in my project. At first I download `FolioReaderKit` example project and install pod like this:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

def shared_pods
  pod 'FolioReaderKit', path: '../'
end

def testing_pods
  pod 'Quick', '1.3.2'
  pod 'Nimble', '7.3.1' 
end

target 'Example' do
  shared_pods
end

target 'Storyboard-Example' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MultipleInstance-Example' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'FolioReaderTests' do
  shared_pods
  testing_pods
end
```

After that I open project and build app. All works fine. Now I trying to add `FolioReaderKit` in my project. I read how to use `Cocoapods` in `GitHub` on `FolioReaderKit` page. And my podfile look like this:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'myProject' do
    pod 'FolioReaderKit'
end
```

But when I use this pod in my app I get next error: `Primary key property 'name' does not exist on object 'RealmSwiftClassPermission'`. Why this happens and how to fix this error?

Comment: Yes I am getting same issue please suggest if you get an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `pod 'FolioReaderKit', path: '../'` with

```
pod 'FolioReaderKit', '~> 1.4.0'
```

Then try to use `pod repo update` and `pod install`

if doesn't work then check [Ravi Panchal's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48657622/8475638)

if Ravi's answer doesn't work check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55898353/8475638) too

Comment: I use this line in folioreaderkit example `pod 'FolioReaderKit', path: '../'` In my project I replace this `pod 'FolioReaderKit'` for this `pod 'FolioReaderKit', '~> 1.4.0'` But its doesn't  help. Other answer not helped too...

Comment: using this getting Realm (3.13.1) instead of Realm (3.17.3) M1 MacBook please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
Open project's pod file

```
pod 'FolioReaderKit', '~> 1.4.0'
```

After that

```
pod repo update
pod install
```

Comment: Have you installed RealmSwift in your pod file

Answer (score 0):

there is a similiar error like yours.
Find it here -> [Github discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457524/primary-key-property-name-does-not-exist-on-object-realmswiftpermissionrole)

Like iShox said already ...

1. open projects podfile
2. `pod 'FolioReaderKit', '~> 1.4.0'`
3. `$ pod install`
4. `$ pod update`
5. Have fun with your new CocoaPod :-)

For the future - when you have any errors on your pods, take a look at the version. You can find it on the github repo and mostly at the beginning of the readme :-)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to delete `FolioReader` cache by using `pod cache clean FolioReaderKit --all` .

This will make sure you are installing the fresh version of the pod on the next install.

2. `pod deintegrate` then `pod install` .

To make sure you are installing the newest version, simply add `pod 'FolioReaderKit', '~> 1.4.0'`

3. Make sure you are opening `xcworkspace` in your project instead of `xcodeproj` .